How to effectively test a Flutter app with network calls when flutter test limits access to plugins?
I'm currently developing a Flutter application and facing challenges with testing. When I run flutter test, I find that it doesn't provide access to plugins and other components available when running the app.
My concern is that if I mock everything, I'm not truly testing anything meaningful. I need to include actual network calls in my tests to ensure that my app and server behave as expected.
What are some recommended approaches to effectively test a Flutter app while including network interactions? Are there best practices for integrating real network calls in tests, or is there a way to configure the flutter test to allow for a more integrated testing environment?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

What plugins and components specifically do you not have access to?
